# MOK signed NVIDIA drivers are not loading after some time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, nvidia, secure-boot

From time to time my NVIDIA drivers (signed with MOK) are not being loaded on my dual boot machine (Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11). I'm resolving the issue by reinstalling the same drivers with the same signing keys.

Signing keys are on the same path all the time (I'm not deleting them or moving somewhere else).

It's constantly happening every 1-2 months. What could cause that?

Edit: I'm only re-installing the drivers (step 6: https://askubuntu.com/a/1049479), re-enroll is not needed

Comment: Do you also re-enroll the same MOK key each time?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not re-enrolling them. I'm just providing paths for existing keys, so drivers can be signed. It looks like the key is already enrolled. Maybe I explained it wrong, I don't have to enter MOK manager on boot and enroll key to make those drivers work. Basically, I'm just doing step 6 from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1049479

Comment: Can signed drivers expire somehow?

Comment: What you're describing is highly unusual and shouldn't be happening. I presume somehow your distro replaces your NVIDIA drivers from time to time. As to why it's happening I've no idea, maybe it's because you receive updates and the kernel driver gets reinstalled automatically e.g. using DKMS? Or you receive kernel updates and it has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting kernel security updates, which include a new kernel package with a new set of kernel modules to match it each time. Apparently you don't have any automation set up to rebuild your NVIDIA kernel modules whenever that happens.

There is a package called `dkms` which can automate the rebuilding of third-party kernel modules on installation of a new kernel image. You should install the `dkms` package using your package manager (e.g. `sudo apt install dkms` or with your preferred GUI tool), and if you are using the driver installer provided by NVIDIA, use the option `--dkms` with the installer.

If you are using the same MOK key each time, there should be no need for the key (re)installation procedure.

If you used Debian/Ubuntu tools to create your MOK, there should be two files in `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/` directory: the private key as `MOK.priv` and the public key as `MOK.der`. But you said you have your own signing keys at some other known path, so you can use them instead.

So, if you are using NVIDIA's installer, you might run it this way:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-<version number>.run --dkms \
    --module-signing-secret-key=/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
    --module-signing-public-key=/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
```

After a successful installation using DKMS, the command `sudo dkms status` should output a list of one or more kernel versions that have the NVIDIA driver modules built for them:

```
nvidia, <driver version>, <kernel version>, x86_64: installed
```